# How do i build namespaces xmlns, xmlns:xsi, and schema xsi:schemalocaton in my XML via VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, namespaces

I need to replicate a xml header:

```
<XDataFeed 
xmlns="http://foo.com/namespace" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .
xsi:schemaLocation="http://foo.com/namespace C:\fooXSD.XML">
```

with my code:

```
'Export the object to XML
                Dim writer As New XmlSerializer(DataFeed.GetType)
                Dim ns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
                ns.Add("xmlns", "http://foo.com/namespace")
                ns.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
                Dim file As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\foo.xml")
                writer.Serialize(file, DataFeed, ns)
                file.Close()
```

and i'm hitting 2 issues:

1. when i try to add my namespace without a prefix for foo.com, it removes all namespaces. My code above adds foo.com's namespace as:

   xmlns:xmlns="http://foo.com/namespace"

which is not correct.  How do i simply add in the namespace without a prefix?

2. i have searched for an hour trying to figure out how to append the attribute "xsi:schemaLocation..." to my xml, though every single example i found uses types in c#, or manipulation to a declared xml doc which are not aplicable to my VB.Net XmlSerializer approach.  How do i go about appending the schemaLocation attribute to my xml by way of the XmlSerializer code above?

I greatly appreciate the assistance. I need to get my XML to pass through via XSD validation to be approved, and this is the final piece that is standing in my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to do this myself.

Don't add your namespace into the `XmlSerializerNamespaces`. Instead, just put it on your parent object. This should make it not have a prefix and just be `xmlns="http://..."`.

```vb
<XmlRoot(Namespace:="http://foo.com/namespace")>
Public Class XDataFeed
    '...
End Class
```

If for some reason it slaps in a dummy prefix like `d1p1`, use `string.Empty` for your prefix and go ahead and add your namespace to the `XmlSerializerNamespaces`.

In order for the SchemaLocation to show up, you can create a dummy property and tag it up accordingly:

```vb
<XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", NameSpace:=XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)>
Public Property SchemaLocation As String
    Get
        Return "http://foo.com/namespace C:\fooXSD.XML"
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        'Ignore... pureley needed for serialization.
    End Set
End Property
```

You are already adding in the `xsi` namespace so it should work just fine if you keep doing that. Just take out your `xmlns` namespace.

In the end you should end up with a class like this:

```vb
<XmlRoot(Namespace:="http://foo.com/namespace")>
Public Class XDataFeed

    <XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", NameSpace:=XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)>
    Public Property SchemaLocation As String
        Get
            Return "http://foo.com/namespace C:\fooXSD.XML"
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            'Ignore... pureley needed for serialization.
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: So close!!! The namespace worked like a charm! Only one item left... when i paste in the schema code i get an error on the NameSpace:=XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace parameter. The error i'm getting is on XmlSchema: System.Data.XMLSchema is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.  Any idea how i clear this error?

Comment: @KevinHenzel Fully qualify it. It's using the wrong class. It lives in the `System.Xml.Schema` namespace.

Comment: You, sir, have saved me!  Thank you so much for your aid!  First time asking a question on this site as i typically find my answers online, but this one is a tough find!  I owe you my gratitude! TY!

Comment: @KevinHenzel No problem. Like I said, I just had to do this yesterday. =)  Don't forget to mark this as the answer since your issue is now resolved.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
<XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace:=**System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace**)>
Public Property SchemaLocation As String
    Get
        Return "*maValeurXsischemaLocation*"
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        'Ignore... pureley needed for serialization.
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Please post in English only